# Is there such a thing as a post-branch git hook?

Tags: git, githooks

I'm aware of the post-checkout git hook, but I'm looking for something that will fire the first time I create a new branch.  In a special case when I'm running `git checkout -b` the post-checkout might be appropriate in this one case, but I'd like to some how capture the event where I've just created a new branch.

I've taken a look at the [git-hooks](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html) doc page, but nothing stands out to me that will work for this case.

Is there such a thing as a post-branch git hook?

Comment: No.  Be aware that branches are simply references whose name starts with `refs/heads/`: you can create or modify one using the "plumbing" command `git update-ref`.  Your best bet may be to have your own shell script you use in place of `git branch` (and see other stackoverflow.com questions about having a `git` alias that checks the sub-command and kind of bypasses git to do your own special stuff, if you want to keep spelling the command `git branch`).

Comment: You might be able to get something the first time you push a branch to a remote repository, but I don't think there is anything for local creation.

Comment: What would be the use case for such a feature? Unless your attempting to use branches in a way that they were never intended to do. Besides all checkouts make it into the reflog removing a need to "record" the sha change manually.

Comment: @torek what's more, you could even create a branch via `echo some_sha1_sum > .git/refs/heads/newbranch`, which is completely outside of `git` and no `git` hook would ever notice it...

Comment: @twalberg: true, but technically cheating :)  I brought up `update-ref` since that's the method you're *supposed* to use in scripts, in general (well, provided calling `git branch` directly is unsuitable for some reason).

Comment: Here's what I'm imagining (possibly a misuse, I'll admit).  Given a new branch I'd have the hook fire up my editor with a templated file (much like a commit message) that would include the 'name of the new branch', the date, and an area: purpose/goal where I'd keep the general idea of the branch even if later that changes.  This would be the first commit to the branch which adds the file branch-desc.txt.  Later, prior to a push, I'd revert this first commit, rebase and squash.  It's a place to stash some notes attached directly to my branch.